# How to develop C # console application for windows 2008 64 bit?

Tags: c#, windows

I want to know that ,can I create a c# console application on my windows 7 pc with visual studio 2010 for a windows 2008 64 bit.If yes,How?

Comment: I have no idea what your problem is. Have you tried making a 64-bit console and run into a problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely - just create a new Console Application project. By default it will create a project with an assembly which styles itself as x86, but you can change that to AnyCPU if you need to. (The 32-bit app will work fine on the 64-bit machine, although obviously it won't be able to use as much memory, or load 64-bit native libraries.)

Answer (score 4):

In your Solution Explorer, right click on your project and select `Properties`.

Under `Build` tab, change `Platform target` to `x64`.